# Custom variable within tag pair?

Tags: templates, variable

I need to restructure the channel entries (I'm trying to group them by one of the channel fields). For example, say I have a list of fruits and each fruit had a color. I'm trying to group these fruits in an associative array by color, like:

```
$fruits['yellow'] = array('fruit_name' => 'banana' ...
```

Once I have this restructured data, I then need to loop over it and output certain mark up.

So far, what I have done is to set `Allow PHP?` to `Yes` and declared an array, built that array within the entries tag pair, and now going to loop through that array and output the markup I need.

This seems messy. Is there a "cleaner" approach?

**UPDATE**

This is how I want to output the data, which I think would be impossible to achieve with an `orderby`:

```
Yellow
 -- Banana
 -- Lemon
 -- Papaya

Red
 -- Apple
 -- Strawberry
 -- Cherry
```

So, I need to loop over the colors, then loop over the fruits within each color. It's a nested array that I need. Using orderby does not give me a nested array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the [orderby](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby) parameter on your custom field, and use PHP to monitor that field, and, each time it changes, perform your custom display behavior?

**Edit 1: Setting up Categories**

It turns out that you should probably be using categories to display your entries. Using your example above, you should setup a Category Group; there are many strategies for managing categories/sub categories; we'll assume you just need a single Category Group called "Colors."

In any event, create the "Colors" category group (Admin > Channel Administration > Categories > [Create a New Category Group] > Name it "Colors" > Add/Edit Categories > etc), then, tie it to your channel (Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Group Assignments > [Category Groups]).

After jumping through those hoops, you'll be able to specify which colors are associated with each entry when editing them.

Once categories are in established, displaying them in a template is straight forward:

```
{exp:channel:categories style="linear"}
  <h3>{category_name}</h3>
  {exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}"}
    <p><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></p>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: I really think I need a nested array. Question updated.

Comment: I guess the followup question would then be asking why you're using a custom field and not a category?

Comment: I'm new to EE. Should "yellow" have been a category instead? If so, how do I do that? I just used a simple Select Dropdown to contain the thing I wanted to group by.

Comment: Yes. I'll put together an answer for you, standby.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html, but I'm not sure if this actually shows me how to set things up. It would be great if I could somehow convert my Select Dropdown to this category feature.

Comment: Insofar as I know, you'd have to go back and setup the categories and update each entry in order for this to work. If that's too much of a hurtle, Mark Croxton's solution looks promising.

Comment: I'm trying your solution. I've created the category group, then associated it with the appropriate channel. When I went to Content -> Publish -> [my channel], I don't see anything different. Nothing for me to set the category of the channel entry. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: OK, I think I created a Category Group only. I created an actual category now, then tied it with the channel. When adding a new channel entry, all I see in the "Category" tab is a checkbox for the category. My category is a Select List, though.

Comment: Categories are displayed with a checkbox, as you mentioned, by default. There could very well be an add-on out there that would display them as a select and/or multi-select, but, I'm not aware of one.

If you don't want the categories displayed in a tab, you could use a custom publish layout... if you need help with that process, I'd propose submitting a new question, as we're starting to drift a long ways from your original question :)

Comment: I don't need a new UI, I guess. Just need to figure out how to use the current one. I don't think the categories I'm selecting are saving properly. Will open a new question for it. Thanks.

Comment: The new question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/struggling-with-categories. Seems like I'm still confused about Categories.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted comments could be the best way to go for you. But if you have valid reasons to use a custom field for fruit colors you can group entries by color with the third-party [NSM Channels](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-channels) add-on (AUD $39.95)

This should work:

```
{exp:nsm_channels:group_entries_by
  group_by="custom_field_color"
  }
  <h3>{custom_field_color}</h3>
  <ul>
  {channel_entries channel="fruit"}
    <li>{title}</li>
  {/channel_entries}
  </ul>
{/exp:nsm_channels:group_entries_by}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you can't use the [entries order by parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby) to order by that field? I think understanding that would help us answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Stash to filter by colour on output with match/against:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="fruit" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="fruit"}   
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:color}{cf_color}{/stash:color}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="fruit" match="#^yellow$#" against="color"}
{title}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev

Comment: Note that a category group for 'Colors' would be a more appropriate grouping solution, unless you have a particular reason to use a custom field.

Comment: No particular reason for using Select Dropdown. I'm still navigating my way around EE. Will look into the categories solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select field type
It creates a drop-down of one or more category group.

Also one of the best category plugins around - http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories
you can use it to generate nested or simple list of categories or custom category fields.